# Angular service registered with container without specifying "providedIn"

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

The angular docs [recommend](https://angular.io/guide/providers#provider-scope) registering a service with the container 1) in the root scope, generally, or 2) in the scope of a particular module.

So in the general case, like this:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
```

However I see lots of code like this:

```
@Injectable()
```

In that case, in which scope will the service be registered? What are the implications of not specifying a scope, and how does that affect tree shaking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of `@Injectable()`,it is registered in component level or module level in `providers` array

Component level:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>{{ title }}</h1>',
    providers: [ExampleService]
})
```

Module Level:

```
@NgModule({
  //other metadata properties
  providers: [ExampleService]
})
```

Comment: Upto Angular 5, we had to add the service in providers of component or module mandatorily. From Angular 6 onwards `@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })` was introduced which means by default it is added in app.module i.e root module

Comment: So there are 3 ways: 1) specify "root" and it's available everywhere, 2) specify "MyModule" and it's available only in "MyModule", and 3) don't specify anything, and it's available everywhere *if you reference it like you showed in your code*?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Visit https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services and go to the section **Providing services**, this has been explained very nicely